# Is the 30 inch apple cinema display supposed to feel hot to the touch after an hour?

Tags: display

I recently bought a 30 inch cinema display and a OEM 150 watt power adapter and hooked it up to my MacPro 3,1.  Both the power supply and the display are very hot to the touch.  Is that normal ?

Answer (score 1):

The clue is in the wattage rating of the power supply: 150W. Yes, those displays do create a lot of heat. They are hot 'to the touch', so that the heat can dissipate through the exterior surfaces.